# nodejs http.get() wont pipe large files or long videos to the reasponse?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, node-modules, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

Sorry for any inconvenience with the question title, but I don't know how to describe issue.

I have the following code to fecth remote video and pipe it to the response (play it in the browser using html5 video tag):

```
const express = require('express')
//url: https://www.example.com/video.mp4
const http = require('https')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    http.get(url, (httpRes) => {
        httpRes.pipe(res)
    })
})
```

And I also tried using **`got`** npm module:

```
got.stream(url).pipe(res)
```

**the problem is**: both methods work just fine if the video duration was not that long (IE 3 minutes), but if it was (IE more than 35 minutes ) it won't fetch the whole video, instead it gives me the first 2:54 minutes.

What could be the problem?
and what can I do to fix it?
Thank you all for any kind of help.

**EDIT:
 MY FULL CODE:**

```
const express = require('express')
const url = 'https://www.example.com/video.mp4'
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('https')
const app = express()
const port = 3000 

// the main request is made by the client to this endopoint '/'
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //the server responds by sending 'player.html' file
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/player.html')
})

// this request is made by the <video> tag in 'player.html'
app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
    http.get(url, (response) => {
        response.pipe(res)
    })
```

player.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls width="100%" height="auto">

        <source src='/video' type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would guess that the browser is running into some internal storage limits and stops collecting the video at some amount of memory usage.  In a more typical video playing from a browser, the video would be requested in chunks (often called ranges).  It would download and buffer a chunk and start playing that.  Sometime before play reaches the end of the chunk, it requests the next chunk and so on.

Comment: If the above theory is correct, then you would want to proxy access to [http range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) so the browser can request ranges.  This would also probably need a `<video>` tag in a web page rather than the way you're doing it now.

Comment: @jfriend00, I do have a <video> tag in the web page, but for some reason I cant pass the video link directly to the <video>  tag. so I want my node server work as a bridge between  the video source and the client (the browser).

Comment: @jfriend00, can I use the data event of the http.get response to play the chunks that are flowing from the video source directly on the browser?

Comment: Well, your code shows a request to `/` that is serving the video so it's hard to understand what your real structure is here.  You could fully proxy a request for the image including full support for an http range request and make a video tag work properly in that way.

Comment: No, that's not the way the chunks need to work.  If the browser request comes from a video tag, then the browser will not request the whole video at once.  It will request a piece and your server code needs to get just that piece and stream back just the piece that is requested.  Right now you're attempting to send the entire video.

Comment: @jfriend00, I don't know what you mean by proxy a request, I'll edit my post for you to see the full structure of my code. and  hope you can help me fix it.

Comment: Can you provide a real video URL you're trying to use so I can see what its server supports?

Comment: It might be useful to read this: [Streaming video in chunks](https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/).

Comment: @jfriend00, sorry for being late to reply, the url works only in my country because it belongs to a local ISP company. I don't think you will be able to fetch it but, here it is: 'https://cdn.shabakaty.com/mp420-240/9E417896-D1F6-1B8F-8BEF-216D411DB50D_video.mp4'

Comment: See https://webomnizz.com/video-stream-example-with-nodejs-and-html5/ for how to support and serve byte ranges with video.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've seen that tutorial before, it's talking about a video that's already existed on my local server. but the video I want to play is on a remote server, that's why I'm using http.get.